# Comparing files in unix columnwise

Tags: files, diff, comm

I want to compare two files with same number of rows and columns with records in same order.
Just want to highlight the differences in the column values if any.

`file A`:

```
1,kolkata,19,ab

2,delhi,89,cd

3,bangalore,56,ef
```

`file B`:

```
1,kolkata,21,ab

2,mumbai,89,gh

3,bangalore,11,kl
```

Considering column `1` as primary key, we have differences in other columns.
I want to highlight those differences.

Output format may be (not sure):

```
record_number,  columns_with_diff
1               3

2               2,4

3               3,4
```

Can `diff` or `comm` solve my problem?
If yes then what would be the exact command?

Comment: Are the blank lines part of your file?

Answer (score 3):

This would be it. Just some style issue with the extra comma at the end of each line.

```
awk '
     BEGIN{ FS=","; ORS="" }

     { 
       # read line from secondary file
       getline aux < "file2"
       split(aux,f2,",")

       # print current line number
       print NR" "

       # process each field in current line
       for(i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
         if ($i!=f2[i]) {
           print i","
         }
       }
       print "\n"
     }
' file1
```

The output:

```
1 3,
2 2,4,
3 3,4,
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it easier with `perl`:

```
$ perl -F',' -anle '
    BEGIN{
        print "record_number,  columns_with_diff";
        $" = ",";
    }
    if (!defined($h{$.})) {
        @{$h{$.}}{0..$#F} = @F[0..$#F];
    } else {
        @diff =  grep { $h{$.}{$_} ne $F[$_] } 0..$#F;
        print "$.\t\t@{[map {$_+1} @diff]}";
    } 
    close ARGV if eof;
' file1 file2
record_number,  columns_with_diff
1       3
2       2,4
3       3,4
```

You should remove blank lines in your input for this works.

**Explanation**

- In `BEGIN` block we just print the header of output, then set list separator to `,`
- `@{$h{$.}}{0..$#F} = @F[0..$#F]`: we create a hash of hashes with the keys of first hash are the line number, each sub hashes has the keys are index of field minus 1, and the values are values coresspond with that fields.

Here we use a hash slice to quickly assign values to hash of hashes.

if you use `Data::Dumper` to print the hash of hashes `%h`, you can see something like this:

```
VAR1 = {
          '2' => {
                   '2' => '89',
                   '0' => '2',
                   '1' => 'delhi',
                   '3' => 'cd'
                 },
          '3' => {
                   '1' => 'bangalore',
                   '3' => 'ef',
                   '0' => '3',
                   '2' => '56'
                 },
          '1' => {
                   '3' => 'ab',
                   '1' => 'kolkata',
                   '0' => '1',
                   '2' => '19'
                 }
        };
```

- If we have created `%h` (`if (!defined($h{$.}))`) - meaning we finished processing `file1` - we just compare each fields of current line with coresspond value in `%h`, storing all the index that different in array `@diff`. `map {$_+1} @diff` restore the column number, because index of array start at 0, column number start at 1.
- `close ARGV if eof` restore `$.` counter.